# Making a 12 hour digital circuit in MULTISIM

Tags: digital-logic, clock, multisim

[image]

I saw a video for building a digital circuit but he uses a different decoder and counter.

Can anyone help me understand how these work and give sources to read more about them?

- the decoder: (4029BD_5V)
- the counters: (4511BD_5V)

Comment: The 4029 is a 4-bit counter and the 4511 is a 7-segment display decoder and driver. You can look up their datasheets to see how they work. Together they make a counter that can count up and down from 0-15 but can only display the numbers 0-9 (if you add a common cathode 7-segment display). I have no idea what video you watched and why you show us this partial circuit.

Comment: [CD4029B](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4029b.pdf), [CD4511B](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4511b.pdf).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i see a video for making a 12 hours digital clock so and he use a decoder and counter i mentioned previously i asked because i didn't fined the same decoder and countrer

Comment: but the circuit i build with using a different decoder and counter after the clock going to 12 the next number show 00 do u know how i fix it ? or give me ur email so i can send u my whole circuit

Comment: You can edit the question to include the complete circuit.

Answer (score 0):

> but the circuit i build with using a different decoder and counter after the clock going to 12 the next number show 00 do u know how i fix it ? or give me ur email so i can send u my whole circuit

You need to set the jam inputs of your 4029 to 0001 and then have whatever is controlling the 4029 pull "preset enable" high when you want it to roll back.  The quick and dirty way to do this is to use the Q1 line for your tens of hours counter.